# Fixing punctuation after a field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Customising a [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) style, I want to ensure that after the title of books only a space is used. If you take a look at one of the standard drivers:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

changing the part about the book title to read

```
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
```

does not work as the various `\newunit` instructions seem to over-ride it even if no additional fields are printed. What's the correct way to say 'the next punctuation must always be just a space'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to section 4.7.3 of the manual, the `\nopunct` macro *"[a]dds an internal marker which will cause the next punctuation command to print nothing."* The following seems to work:

```
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \nopunct
```

Comment: Excellent: I knew there would be a way, but was failing to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to replace every following `\newunit` by `\setunit*{\newunitpunct}`, as the starred variant of `\setunit` prints the punctuation only if the previous command (`\printtext`, `\printfield`, `\printlist`, `\printnames`, `\bibstring`) was executed. Although I am not sure if this works, it is worth a try.