# How to avoid superfluous punctuation for shorthand in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I would like to have the shorthand printed in the bibliography in square brackets *before* the bibliography item. I adapted [this answer by lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52597/1376) which works with one problem: if there is no author, there is a superfluous dot. This comes obviously from the `\labelnamepunct` which is set by the `\setunit` command of the bibliography drivers. Is there an easy way to avoid the output of the `\labelnamepunct`?

Here is an example that illustrates the problem (KpV is correct, CTAN has the superfluous punctuation):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InBook{kant:kpv,
  shorthand   = {KpV},
  hyphenation     = {german},
  author      = {Kant, Immanuel},
  bookauthor      = {Kant, Immanuel},
  title       = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},
  shorttitle      = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},
  booktitle   = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft. Kritik der Urtheilskraft},
  maintitle   = {Kants Werke. Akademie Textausgabe},
  volume      = {5},
  publisher   = {Walter de Gruyter},
  location    = {Berlin},
  date        = {1968},
  pages       = {1--163}
}
@Online{ctan,
  shorthand       = {CTAN},
  hyphenation     = {american},
  title       = {CTAN},
  subtitle    = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  date        = {2006},
  url         = {http://www.ctan.org},
  urldate     = {2006-10-01}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
     \addspace}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here is what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\nopunct` to the redefinition of the `begentry` bibmacro. This way, the next punctuation command will print nothing.

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
     \nopunct\addspace}}
```

[image]

See also my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12164/510) to [Fixing punctuation after a field in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/fixing-punctuation-after-a-field-in-biblatex).

Comment: Wow, this was easy! How come that I did not know `\nopunct` yet …? Shame on me.